# How to search files in sub-folders instead of parent/main folder?

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

I am using `Google Drive API`. If I search for files with query 
`id = '1234567'` and `name = 'hello world'`, it finds all files and folders located directly in the folder whose ID is `1234567` and whose title is `hello world`.

Is there any query to find files with name `hello world` located in any sub folders of `1234567`?

Answer (score 0):

A query can alternatively be executed only in a specific folder using an instance of the DriveFolder class

You can use `Childer:list` to view list of a folder's childer. To list all children of the root folder, use the alias `root` for the *folderId* value. Note that every request requires authorization.

Requests with [children.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) accept the q parameter, which is a search query combining one or more search terms.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/folderId/children

private static void printFilesInFolder(Drive service, String folderId) throws IOException
{
    Children.List request = service.children().list(folderId);

    do
    {
        try
        {
            ChildList children = request.execute();

            for (ChildReference child : children.getItems())
            {
                System.out.println("File Id: " + child.getId());
            }

            request.setPageToken(children.getNextPageToken());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    }
    while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
}
```

Comment: Thats not a valid solution as there could be any number of sub folders recursively.